# CIM Abstract class can still be instantiated on Windows?

Tags: abstract-class, wmi, cim, mi

On Windows 10/11:

```
Get-CimClass -ClassName CIM_BIOSElement | select *
```

Shows
CimClassQualifiers  : {Locale, UUID, abstract}
Yet it can perfectly be instantiated:

```
> Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_BIOSElement | Select-Object -Property *

Status                         : OK
Name                           : Version 2.27
Caption                        : Version 2.27
SMBIOSPresent                  : True
Description                    : Version 2.27
Output truncated
```

Why? Is this qualifier for other languages?

I was expecting error message of some kind.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (sanitized if necessary) both outputs. Runs the same on my W10/PowerShell5.1 as well as pwsh (PowerShell 7.4).